# Selenium button identification multiples on page

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium with C#. I am unable to click on a button using its text because I have multiple buttons on the screen that have the same text. There is a "store" property for the button that could help me identify which button i need to select, but I am new to selenium and struggling to identify the button using this value.

```
 - <a href="#" class="cta-button cta-begin-order" store="1">Order</a>
 - <a href="#" class="cta-button cta-begin-order" store="2">Order</a>
 - <a href="#" class="cta-button cta-begin-order" store="3">Order</a>
```

I need to identify one these buttons and click it based on the store I am currently browsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go with Xpath to find the elements.There are many [links](http://hedleyproctor.com/2011/05/tutorial-writing-xpath-selectors-for-selenium-tests/) available on how to write Relative Xpaths

```
//a[@class='cta-button cta-begin-order'][@store='2']
//a[@store='2']
//a[text()='Order'][2] //Index based
```

Comment: Thank you for your solutions, but more importantly the links to help me understand this going further. Much appreciated.

Comment: As I said there are many links available Just google it and also read about css selectors